# Convergent sequences in discrete metric space

Tags: real-analysis

A discrete metric is given by

$$d(x, y) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x =  y \\
1 & \text{if } x\neq y.
\end{cases}$$

I have proved that this is a metric. My question is: which sequences converge in a discrete metric space?

Please be detailed in your answer so that I can understand the reasoning. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:**

Choose $\varepsilon<1$, e.g. $\;\varepsilon=\frac12$. What does $d(x_n,l)<\varepsilon\;$  mean for $x_n$?